# Mostrar gráficos (<p:chart>) de una List<LineChartModel> en primefaces, jsf

Tags: java, jsf, lista, primefaces

Buen día, estoy intentando mostrar gráficos desde un **List LineChartModel** con primefaces. Lleno la lista correctamente desde mi código java, pero para la vista uso el **ui:repeat** para recorrer la lista de la siguiente manera:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{sobredimensionado.listAreaModel}" var="a" >
  <p:panel>
    <p:chart type="line" model="#{a}"  style="width:900px;height: 400px" widgetVar="chart" />
  </p:panel>
</ui:repeat>
```

Pero de esta manera solo me muestra correcto el último gráfico de la lista , pero deja los espacios de los anteriores.
Si alguien ya se topó con esta situación espero me pueda ayudar, o dar alguna idea.

Gracias
Luis E. Luza

Comment: Veo por tu comentario que has encontrado la solución; puedes escribirla tú mismo como tal y marcarla como correcta (o marcar la de Garrizano si también es correcta). De esta forma cuando alguien busque preguntas relacionada, verá rápidamente que la tuya tiene una respuesta correcta y es más probable que la consulte.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el componente de PrimeFaces `p:dataGrid` de manera similar. Espero con eso te funcione:

```
<p:dataGrid var="a" value="#{sobredimensionado.listAreaModel}" columns="4" layout="grid">
    <p:panel>
        <p:chart type="line" model="#{a}"  style="width:900px;height: 400px" widgetVar="chart" />
    </p:panel>            
</p:dataGrid>
```

Comment: Gracias Garrizano, mira que funciona de las 2 formas (la que yo indico y la que tu indicas), solo un detalle en los 2 ejemplos, le estaba colocando el atributo **widgetVar="chart"** a todos. Por ende sobreescribía todo y solo me mostraba el último. Le quité el atributo **widgetVar="chart"** y funcionó ok. Espero a alguien le sirva esta experiencia. Gracias!